# Polarity of inductor in GNSS antenna design

Tags: inductor, polarity, gnss

I was assembling a PCB today which had a circuit to connect the main module to an active GNSS antenna.  I noticed that the inductor, a 47nH [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/murata_mure-s-a0006150565-1-1763976.pdf), had polarity markings on it, but I was unsure the proper orientation.

[image: circuit]

Could someone explain how this inductor could be polar and which orientation is correct in respect to the circuit diagram?  I am not an expert in circuits by any means but I thought that an inductor was just a wound coil.

Comment: [Related.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359207/why-does-this-two-terminal-inductor-have-a-polarity)

Comment: @JRE thanks for sharing this link.  From what I gathered the inductance can vary with placement and one should keep placement on all boards the same when possible.  Also there are a few placements that give inductance values closer to the spec than others?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it depends on what other components and materials are near the inductor.  The idea is to be consistent rather than achieving some specific inductance.

Answer (score 2):

"Polarity" is a misnomer here.  An inductor is just a coil of wire, after all.  But the two ends could do different things.

If it makes any difference, it would have to do with the internal construction of the inductor -- either it's shielded, and there's a break in the shield at one end or another, or it's multiple-layer and the polarity mark indicates the outer (or inner)layer, etc.  Differences such as these may have bearing on how you locate other components, or whether you put a ground plane underneath the thing.

I would get onto the MuRata website and dig.  See if there's a page on the website or in the catalog of that series of inductor, and see if it says what the polarity mark means.