# Inductor on a GPS receiver

Tags: inductor, coil, gps

I'm soldering the circuit of a high accuracy (and cost) GPS receiver with an active antenna.

The inductor L1 in this diagram has a polarity marked by a dark band on one end.

Which side do I put the dark band to, aerial or VCC_RF?

L1 part number is [LQG15HS47NJ02D](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811081515_Murata-Electronics-LQG15HS47NJ02D_C97998.pdf)

[image: Polarity Marking of Inductor]

[image: Schematic of active antenna]

Comment: [You might want to take a look at this other question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359207/why-does-this-two-terminal-inductor-have-a-polarity)

Answer (score 6):

It generally indicates the winding direction, just like the dot you see in a transformer or a choke drawing. It shouldn't be taken as a "polarity" as the inductors have none.

The idea of putting the direction mark on the coil you linked can be to give you a hint about possible effects (such as mutual inductance) when two or more of them are placed close to each other, especially in parallel (not electrically, but mechanically).

[image]

<sup>Sorry for my horrible MSPaint skills</sup>

It's also possible for the inductor to show slightly different properties when mounted differently. Due to the mechanical design/construction and practical imperfections, the stray capacitance, therefore the impedance the chip exhibits may change when mounted differently.

For your application, if you are about to assemble multiple, try to mount all the chip inductors in the same way up.

Comment: how does the winding direction change when the component is turned in the opposite  direction?

Comment: @jsotola it doesn't. Did I say so?

Comment: I got confused by the `It generally indicates the winding direction` ... I realize  that the meaning of the marking is explained in the datasheet